# Identic name for Headers in Jmeter

Tags: http, header, xmlhttprequest, jmeter

How can I set multiple headers in Jmeter (HTTP Header Manager), header that are all named `Content-Type`, without having the problem that only the first is taken into consideration?

Ex: I set 1st header `Content-Type=<value1>` and 2nd header to `Content-Type=<value2>`. After I use the first header for login, my other HTTP requests fail because the second header is ignored.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you can try to use [HTTP Raw Request](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/RawRequest) custom sampler as ultimate solution.